# How do use destruct and create correctly

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal

I have a Form. When the user clicks the TESTBUTON an array is generated (here with a loop) and an array is filled. (that works).
Now the user will be able to change some parameters an hit the button again.
Than I want to clear / free / destroy the old array an create it new.

I found a lot of examlpes for that but they not work (because I do not know where exatly to place the different procedures). 
So I made this samplescript with all the sections.
Can someone move my procedures to the rigth place or send me an example that shows the correct implementation.

```
unit frmmywindow;

interface

uses 
type 

  TArrayA = record
        Field1:integer;
        Field2:integer;
        Field3:integer;
        Field4:integer;
        String5:string;
         //other fields, strings, integers..
      end; 

  private
    { private declarations }

  public
    { public declarations }
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  var ArrayA : array of TarrayA;

implementation 

destructor TArrayA.Destroy;
begin
  ArrayA.Free;
  inherited;
end; 

procedure TArrayA.Free;
begin
     if Assigned(self) then Destroy;
end;     

procedure TForm1.btnTest(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: integer;
  reccount: integer;
begin
  ArrayA.free:
  ArrayA.create;
  reccount := 1000;
  for x := 1 to reccount do
  begin
        setLength(ArrayA,x+1); 
         ArrayA[x].field1 := 2000 - x;
         ArrayA[x].field2 := x;
         ArrayA[x].field3 := x;
         ArrayA[x].field4 := x;
         ArrayA[x].string5 := 'str' + inttostr(x);
  end;    
end;
```

Comment: Why not read a decent Pascal/Delphi tutorial?

Comment: `array of TArrayA` is dynamic array. You can add/remove its memory using SetLength(). Try search engine with keyword `how to remove dynamic array`

Comment: `TArrayA` is a **`record`**. They do not have destructors. Only objects of type `class` (i.e., derived from `TObject`) have destructors. And you should not code `Free` at all, not even for objects. It is inherited from `TObject`. You should, as @Andreas said, really, really read a proper tutorial on FreePascal before you start guessing. The above is pure guesswork.

Comment: FWIW, the fact that you think of the source code above as a "script" is quite telling. It is a compiled language. Do not confuse those.

Comment: thanks Zamrony and Rudy for your helpful comments

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of issues.

- The main issue is that `TArrayA` is a **record** (normally I would link to the DocWiki documentation for *structured types*, but it seems to be down right now). Records are not **classes**, they **don't have a *destructor*** and **you should not call `Free` on them**. Records are so called [value types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type). They don't even have a proper **constructor**, even if the syntax suggests they do. Record "constructors" are mere initializers.
- Another issue is that you should never code `Free` yourself, not even for **classes**. `Free` is inherited from the root for all class instances, `TObject`. For classes, if you want to give it a **destructor**, **override** the inherited destructor:

  ```
  destructor Destroy; override;
  ```

#### So the answer is: you don't use nor define them at all, for records.

How you should declare, define and use them for **classes** is described in the documentation.

---

*As I already commented, you should get better acquainted with the language. I suggest you read the **Delphi** or **Object Pascal Language Guide** (name differs, depending on version), which is part of the documentation that is installed with Delphi.*